# check box with date module

Tags: 7

I need a solution for reservation, for example i have a swimming pool and i want to Reserve it, the visitor will choose the time he want, let me say i will select the start and end date (the reservation time) mmmm in our example from 8 am to 9am, what i need to display the available reservation time like this:

[image]

And the visitor can select one hour or more to reserve the swimming pool.
Is there a module can do this?and if not is there a reservation module can do what i nees by another way? thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, there  is no module which will display exact User Interface as check-boxes that will integrate with date module.

What i would like to suggest is to create time field to display from and to time of timing slots using date module.

If you need exact User interface what you are asking then follow below steps.

1. Add checkboxes field with different timings.
2. Then create date from and to time fields.
3. Hide date from and to fields using css.
4. On click of check-boxes update the hidden date from & to fields using jquery or javascript, so that you can use Date module features.

Comment: i need to to display the available time dynamically because i have a lot of places to reserve.thanks for your suggestion my friend :D

Comment: In that case you can use form alter technique to alter the form and add checkboxes based on the available timings.... http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7